# Console : How to run a specific command when pressing a key

Tags: linux, console, alsa, keymaps

I try to have the volume keys working on my laptop in pure console mode (Debian installed without X).

I can manage sound volume with alsa commands, but I'd like to assign them to those keys.

I know keycode thanks to the `showkey` command, but now I can't figure out where to assign a specific command to them. Is it in keymaps ? How ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you can use `bind` e.g.

```
bind -x '"\C-g": ls'
```

will make ctrl-g run the ls command

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Seems to work, but only in Bash shell right ? I'm looking for something running in the background and available whatever the context.